# Select N rows before and after given row with condition

Tags: php, mysql

```
id  title   cat lang
6101    AAba    1   1
6102    AAad    4   2
6103    AAaf    4   2
6104    AAa 1   1
6105    AAtar   4   2
6106    AAao    1   1
6107    ABya    4   2
6108    ABar    4   2
6109    ACar    1   2
6110    BCad    3   1
6111    CCas    4   1
6112    DCas    4   2
6113    GCaz    2   2
6114    FCaew   2   2
6115    FCaw3   4   2
6116    FCa3    1   1
6117    FCa4    4   2
6118    FCa5    2   1
6119    FCa6    4   2 --- last id
```

Table news, id is primary key, title - is title field, 
cat - there are four types of categories of news, lang - language code 1 or 2.

I want to achieve following:
1) Case **Edit news** - id is available - for example 6111, lang is 1, cat is 4
I want to collect these id and titles:

```
6119
6117
6115
6112
6109
6105
6103
6102
```

which are the opposite language - lang is 2, the same category cat is 4 and 
within range of 4 (or n) id before and after given id 6111
also ordered desc

2) Case **Add news** - id is not available, or after insert in php is mysql_insert_id()
the same functionality - last 10 id with the same cat = 4 and the opposite lang = 2

So far I have tried this:

for case 1) php snippet:

```
   $id = 6111;
    $lang = 1;
    $tip = 4;
    $sql = "SELECT id, title 
            FROM pubs 
            WHERE id BETWEEN ".($id-4)." AND ".($id+4). " AND 
            tip = ".$tip." AND 
            lang <> ".$lang." 
            ORDER BY id DESC ";
```

**BUT** this gets 4 id before and after the id, not from the collection of id I need .

for case 2)

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title 
        FROM news 
        WHERE cat = 4 AND 
        lang <> 1 
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

This seem to be working, but may be I'm wrong.

Is there any way to achieve Case 1 this with php and mysql?
Better way for case 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you only have the `$id`, this horrible looking beast is the best I can come up with. I'm fairly sure there's a tidier way to do it, but I *think* this will work (**FIXED**)

```
$id = 6111;

$query = "
  SELECT `id`, `title`
  FROM `news`
  WHERE `id` IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT `id`
      FROM `news`
      WHERE `cat` = (
        SELECT `cat`
        FROM `news`
        WHERE `id` = ".$id."
      ) AND `lang` != (
        SELECT `lang`
        FROM `news`
        WHERE `id` = ".$id."
      ) AND `id` < ".$id."
      ORDER BY `id` DESC
      LIMIT 4
    ) `lower`
  ) OR `id` IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT `id`
      FROM `news`
      WHERE `cat` = (
        SELECT `cat`
        FROM `news`
        WHERE `id` = ".$id."
      ) AND `lang` != (
        SELECT `lang`
        FROM `news`
        WHERE `id` = ".$id."
      ) AND `id` > ".$id."
      ORDER BY `id` ASC
      LIMIT 4
    ) `upper`
  )
  ORDER BY `id` DESC
";
```

Comment: @mellamokb Incredibly ugly, I feel sure there is a more efficient way to do it but right now I can't for the life of me figure out how. At least not in a single query, I suppose one could cache the results of the inner-most queries in variables, but I suspect the extra DB traffic would counter out the gain.

Comment: lol, never seen this error before: `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dabe3/1

Comment: @DaveRandom - Thank you, but got error #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' - will try in another environment. What is your version of MySQL?

Comment: ok. this seems to work, but still needs to be cleaned up a bit: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1933d/3

Comment: @mellamokb I found another (slightly weird) workaround [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?86,14788,239000#msg-239000) which also [works](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1933d/4). Editing my answer with new query.

Comment: PHP option with some array and row number was also considered, but still no luck. Also may be more queries - I can get the results in PHP.

Comment: @DaveRandom - Thank you! Tested in my real environment - it works!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might work:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM pubs 
        WHERE tip = ".$tip." AND lang <> ".$lang." 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT ".($id-4).",".($id+4);
```

There may be a more elegant solution, but this gets the job done.

Comment: `LIMIT 6107, 6115` (for example) will grab the `6115` rows following the `6107`th row.  I don't think that solves the OP's problem.

Comment: well, i thought about this, but $id doesn't change to id from the select - it stays the same. @Connor

Comment: @mellamokb - the idea is to get 4 rows before and after 6111 but where ids are not consequent values

Comment: @user1408669: I understand what *you* want, and this is an incorrect answer.  That's my point.

Comment: @mellamokb - yes, that is not the correct answer to my problem.